# Build failed! message, can't build apk in App Inventor

Tags: android, build, build-process

I'm currently working on a bit bigger project in app inventor. I basically finished it, and have had no problem downloading the apk. Just wanting to change some information however, I can no longer download the apk. Also trying to download old saves doesn't work. Much smaller projects is working however.

The trouble message I'm getting is "Build failed! Can not contact the BuildServer at buildserver.appinventor.mit.edu"

Now on my third day of trying, without success.

Anyone no whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Check here http://appinventor.mit.edu/releaseupdate/

Build Server Problems (September 21, 2013)
We are aware of problems building (aka packaging) medium to larger projects. We are working with Google Engineers to resolve this problem as quickly as possible.

Only reason could be size of your apk file.